# RichtextBox automatically changes text direction to RightToLeft

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a LeftToRight RichTextBox.

I'm catching the `KeyUp` event and doing some modifications with the `SelectedText` in the RichTextBox.

However I'm expierencing a strange issue. After I replace the SelectedText, the direction of the RichTextBox turns to RightToLeft.

Before CTRL+R

[image]

After

[image]

Here is my code (only CTRL+R is causing the issue) :

```
    private void tbSource_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        string appendTag, selectedText;
        appendTag = string.Empty;
        if (e.Control)
        {
            selectedText = tbSource.SelectedText;
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.U:
                    appendTag = @"<U>{0}</U>";
                    break;
                case Keys.B:
                    appendTag = @"<B>{0}</B>";
                    break;
                case Keys.R:
                    appendTag = @"<ruby>{0}<rt></rt></ruby>";
                    break;
                case Keys.T:
                    appendTag = @"（　　）";
                    break;
                default:
                    appendTag = @"";
                    break;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U || e.KeyCode == Keys.B || e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
            {
                selectedText = string.Format(appendTag, selectedText);
                tbSource.SelectedText = selectedText;
            }
            else {
                tbSource.AppendText(appendTag);
            }    
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

WinForms RichTextBox has some predefined keyboard shortcuts and *CTRL+R* is the one that changes the direction of the text to RightToLeft.

You can set the property **ShortcutsEnabled** to false and remove all keyboards shortcuts (this includes useful ones like CTRL+C and CTRL+V) or you can change your code setting the KeyEventArgs property SuppressKeyPress to true.

But you need to use the *KeyDown* event handler not the *KeyUp* (I suppose that KeyUp is too late to suppress anything)

```
    private void tbSource_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        .......
            case Keys.R:
                appendTag = @"<ruby>{0}<rt></rt></ruby>";
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;
    }
```

The list of keyboard shortcuts is defined in the docs for the [ShortcutsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_ShortcutsEnabled) property

Comment: Ah. I was about to post a comment about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+R is a default shortcut that changes the direction to RightToLeft. Set the ShortcutsEnabled property of your RichtTextBox to false.
For more information on this property go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_ShortcutsEnabled)